# How do control the start date in DATESYTD and DATESQTD (for example: whether it is calendar year, ISO year and fiscal year)?

Tags: dax, ssas, ssas-tabular

Here are my DAX formula's for YTD and QTD calculations.

```
Sales YTD := CALCULATE( [Total Sales], DATESYTD( 'Date'[Date] ) )

Sales QTD := CALCULATE( [Total Sales], DATESQTD( 'Date'[Date] ) )
```

The date table has dates from 01-01-2020 to 31-12-2040

What is the logic used by the DATESYTD and DATESQTD to derive the 1st date of the year (DATESYTD) and first date of the quarter (DATESQTD)? For example - How do I make it use the start date based on either of the following: calendar year, ISO year and fiscal year ?

Answer (score 2):

For the [DATESYTD](https://dax.guide/datesytd/), you can control the start of the year, by setting the year end date. The default with out this option will be the normal calendar year.

```
DATESYTD('Date'[Date]', "03-31")
```

This will start the YTD calculation from the "01-04" (Normal UK tax year)

For variations between Calendar, ISO and Fiscal years, you'll have to create individual measures, a switch based on a selection, or use a calculation group to drive your YTD measures.

DATESQTD doesn't have the same option. You'll need a well-formed calendar table for the other 'To Date' options.

Update: for week related start/end year, best to check out the [dax patterns approach](https://www.daxpatterns.com/week-related-calculations/)

Comment: Not always 1st April is the start of year. For example it can be the 1st week of April that has Monday in it. Can we handle this situation?

Comment: You'll need an end of fiscal year in your calendar table that you can reference in that option part of DATESTYD, that would be the best way